# Как изменить значение поля модели с ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

models.py:

```
class NotesCats(models.Model):
    cats = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = True, verbose_name='Категории для записной')

class Notebook(models.Model):
    cat = models.ForeignKey(NotesCats, null=True, related_name='категория')
```

При попытке изменить в консоле значение cat экземпляра класса Notebook выдаётся ошибка:

```
>>> nn = Notebook.objects.get(id = 78)
>>> nn
<Notebook:  Казаченко, Юрий, Николаевич >
>>> nn.cat = 'семья'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 366, in __set__
self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))
ValueError: Cannot assign "'\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8c\xd1\x8f'": "Notebook.cat" must be a "NotesCats" instance.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8c\xd1\x8f'": "Notebook.cat" must be a "NotesCats" instance.
```

Непосредственно означает что значение поля `cat` должно быть экземпляром `NotesCats` а никак не строкой.

```
>>> nn = Notebook.objects.get(id=78)
>>> nn
<Notebook:  Казаченко, Юрий, Николаевич >
>>> cat = NotesCats(cats='семья')
>>> cat.save()
>>> nn.cat = cat
```

Comment: только к сожалению в этом случае в NotesCats добавляется ещё одно поле, со значением 'семья', а хотелось чтобы значение перезаписывалось со старого на новое

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> nn.cat.cats = 'семья'
```